# spring-kafka java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: apache-kafka

We haven't upgraded the kafka client library version in a while.

kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar

Stacktrace:

```
2022-01-20 12:06:23,937 ERROR [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | prod] internals.AbstractCoordinator$HeartbeatThread (AbstractCoordinator.java:1083) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=prod] Heartbeat thread failed due to unexpected error
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LogContext$AbstractKafkaLogger.addPrefix(LogContext.java:66) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LogContext$LocationAwareKafkaLogger.writeLog(LogContext.java:434) [kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LogContext$LocationAwareKafkaLogger.info(LogContext.java:382) [kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.markCoordinatorUnknown(AbstractCoordinator.java:729) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.markCoordinatorUnknown(AbstractCoordinator.java:724) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$HeartbeatThread.run(AbstractCoordinator.java:1031) [kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:?]
```

Could there be a memory leak in this version of kafka-clients? Is an upgrade needed?

In the redundant tomcat server (which become primary since the primary server crashed due to OOM), we noticed that the number of blocked-count on the kafka-consumer threads is really huge in the order 4580000, the duration of this JVM is ~5 days 12 h. We got these numbers from Java Mission Control.

Is it normal to see such numbers for the blocked-count?

Comment: Does the same happen if you do upgrade? Note: `spring-kafka` is somewhat particular about the versions that are used

Comment: Thank you for the response. We haven't upgraded in a while as it seemed to be stable. We're adding it to our roadmap for a future iteration. But currently, I'd like to know if the blocked counts in JMC are out of the normal and would like to know if it is contributing to the OOM.

Comment: I'm not sure what a "blocked count" is, but yeah, 4.5 million consumer threads seems like a problem